# Difference between limber and limp

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

Are this words similar because for what ive seen on tv they mean to let your body flexible or something like that
“Stay limber and don’t fight against the flow”
“(Someone is about to be carried upside down) Go limp”
“Close the air suply of the animal until it goes completely limp”

Comment: Why, it's the difference between night and day. :) Being limber has connotations of flexibility, agility, even athleticism. Being limp has connotations of lifelessness, death, weakness.

Answer (score 4):

In brief, **limber** refers to a body that is quite able to flex, and **limp** refers to an appendage which is unable to become rigid.

If your arm is badly injured, it may hang limp at your side.

A gymnast does many exercises to become as limber as possible.